# Is there experimental verification for small QCD coupling?As

Tags: quantum-field-theory

As I understand Perturbation Theory does not work for QCD at strong coupling. And I am lead to believe experimentally, strong coupling constant has been measured?

Is there experimental measurements showing coupling is low for some regime of QCD?

Answer (score 4):

The strong coupling constant $\alpha_s$ is not a pure number: it depends on the energy scale, say $Q$, at which you measure it. Once you measure $\alpha_s(Q^2)$ at one value of $Q$, you can in principle compute the entire function $\alpha_s(Q^2)$ in perturbation theory for all $Q$. However, as you remark, this function blows up as $Q \simeq \Lambda_\text{QCD}$ so its predictions are not reliable at low energies. On the other hand, $\alpha_s(Q^2)$ decreases logarithmically as $Q \to \infty$ so you can robustly predict this curve at high energies.

You're asking about comparison of $\alpha_s(Q^2)$ to experiment. Over the past decades many experiments have probed these theoretical predictions (actually, I'm pretty sure that various experiments were performed way before QCD was properly understood, but that's a different story). A modern-day plot is shown in Fig 9.3 of http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-qcd.pdf (page 39). This plot has a few features. One, even by eye you can see that $\alpha_s(Q^2)$ decreases logarithmically with $Q$. Second, you see that some very different experiments agree beautifully with one another. Finally, you see that $\alpha_s$ becomes small, of order $0.1$, at energy scales of the order 100 GeV-1 TeV.

Comment: Thank you very much.  So would it be fair to say, thus, Perturbative QCD is valid in say Q = 100 GeV to 1 TeV, and has good agreement with experiments? As I understand, Non-Perturbative QCD would be important for binding and confinement, which should be lower than 1 GeV (say energy of a hadron)?

Comment: @user47548 Below about $100\,\mathrm{MeV}$ it turns out that effective degrees of freedom are more descriptive than fundamental ones and you use meson exchange theories like Quantum Hadron Dynamics to describe nuclear physics. The range between $100\,\mathrm{MeV}$ and a few tens of GeV is sometimes called the transition regime, and there is no single reliable way to work theoretical problems in that range. Indeed, probing transition regime physics is the the main mission of [CEBAF](https://www.jlab.org/visitors/science/).